# Kernel failed to build due to sys/types.h not found in yocto dunfell environment

Tags: build, linux-kernel, yocto, systypes.h

I am trying to build a custom Linux kernel derived from 4.19 version in yocto dunfell environment. Compiling the kernel by calling top level makefile from the kernel recipe. Here compilation failed as it failed to find sys/types.h header.

On look into recipe sysroot,  I could see types.h is available there but seems it's not reflecting at compile time.

Any pointers on this?

Yocto version:dunfell

Thanks

Comment: Please, more details about compilation output. E.g. show **exact error message**.

Comment: Are you following the directions in Documentation/admin-guide/README.rst?